# Is it possible to resolve inline placeholders in Thymeleaf without adding quotes?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I'm resolving placeholders in a Javascript file processed by Thymeleaf. One placeholder [[${uniqueNr}]] a.o. is used inside the name of a Javascript function. The placeholder is resolved, but quotes are added: "12345". This is not a good idea for inside a functionname.

I've tried several Thymeleaf template modes, but that does not seem to make a difference. I hoped numbers (Long) would not get quotes, but that is not the case. And it is of course not possible to specify an inline attribute, because it is pure Javascript.

How do I prevent the quotes from being added?

An example was requested:

```
function resizeIframe[[${uniqueNr}]](iframeid) {...}
```

Results in

```
function resizeIframe"12345"(iframeid) {...}
```

That is what I see. The uniqueNr is of class Long.

Comment: Since there is no code, not sure how anyone can help.  Thymeleaf definitely doesn't add quotes to values though ([see this example where I was unable to reproduce your behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAxm7.jpg)).

Comment: I see. I'll take another good look. (Can't get to my code from this computer.)

Comment: The closing `}` is missing in Your expression (after `uniqueNr`), but I guess it is just a typo in example, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is. But I found the issue. The Long was somewhere sneakily converted to a String after all. And that resulted in the quotes.  Thanks @metroids for verifying that it should work and forcing me to re-examine the code. Still, I would not mind being able to insert a text without mandatory quotes.

Answer (score 0):

For an unescaped fragment You may use the `[(...)]` notation:

```html
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    function resizeIframe[(${uniqueNr})](iframeid) {
    }
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

This should work even if the `uniqueNr` is a `String` unless it contains special characters (e.g. quotes).